# Android Screen On different phones

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on android. I implemented an application. But application screen changes when I check it in different phone. Screen is not compatible. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Design your layout to fit for multiple screen dimension. Make use of dimens.xml to mention the size of the views. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a app support multiple screen device, you can use put layout here

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

and you can set each layout accordingly to device size by selecting preview all option or selecting particular screen

Answer (score 0):

Create your layout to support multiple screen by using layout alternate resources

```
  res/layout/main.xml
  res/layout-large/main.xml
  res/layout-sw600dp
```